# How to launch a program on different desktop, using sysinternals desktops

Tags: virtual-desktop, sysinternals

Is there a way to start a program on a different desktop?  Say if Desktop 2 is currently displayed, how could I open Notepad on Desktop 4?

Comment: If you are on Windows 10, sysinternals desktops dating from 2012 is not required.

Comment: @harrymc maybe not, but the difference between windows 10 virtual desktop and sysinternals desktops can be justified by security concern. Sysinternas desktop creates real desktops instead of one desktop with 4 virtual spaces, which makes it more lightweight and more secure. You cannot move an app from one desktop to the other and everything runs in its own security state, meaning, one app in desktop 1 cannot know that app y runs in desktop 2, nor steal info from it.

Comment: @LPChip: Sysinternals uses another desktop object, which blocks program hooks between desktops. In all other aspects the desktops are not isolated.

Comment: @harrymc https://scorpiosoftware.net/2019/02/17/windows-10-desktops-vs-sysinternals-desktops/

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create a program for launching an executable on another
desktop of Sysinternals Desktops.

This is possible to do with the Windows
[CreateProcess function](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw)
by specifying the desktop name in the
[STARTUPINFO structure](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/ns-processthreadsapi-startupinfoa)
member of `lpDesktop`.

The format is `windowstation\desktop` and may look like
"winsta0\Sysinternals Desktop 1".

To find the names of the Sysinternals desktop objects
you may use
the
[winsta tool](https://github.com/zodiacon/winsta) that enumerates
window stations and desktops in the current session
(although you will need to compile it yourself).

Reference: [Windows 10 Desktops vs. Sysinternals Desktops](https://scorpiosoftware.net/2019/02/17/windows-10-desktops-vs-sysinternals-desktops/).

Comment: Sounds promising.  Can I do this from a bat or cmd file?

Comment: Yes, but you will need to first program yourself the launcher, probably in C, because Sysinternals does not provide it.

Comment: I think that will be beyond my capabilities. :(